# change text of an image depending on device language Android

Tags: android, screen

photo: https://imageshack.com/i/f0LwsdJPj

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/xq90/540/LwsdJP.jpg

There is my draft, it is supposed to be like a "card library". My idea was to copy this "draf" and to have 1 pic.png for every card on the library, then when user drags the screen to one side, or touches the arrows it changes picture.

I have some questions. Is there any other way more efficient to do this? like having the same background for all them then changing only text inside them?

I'm doing it with canvas, i do: bitmapFactory.decode image ... then draw bitmap somewhere on the screen. Then, it's not an imageview so I don't know how to change text depending on device language.

Other solution could be something like canvas.WriteText somewhere but it doesn't exist, does it?

Last but not least, I have another problem with this "card" library. The "stars" drawn next to the numbers, should be shining or not depending on the user has the star or not. Do I have to copy an image with every combination? or is there any way to change only 1 part of the picture without building it with photoshop?

Comment: `something like canvas.WriteText` you mean `canvas.drawText`. For your reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)

Comment: ooh thanks I haven't adviced this function exists! anyway, any other ideas for the rest?

Comment: `how to change text depending on device language` Use localization. For your reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: `Do I have to copy an image with every combination?` 2 stars only: shiny, opaque (I'd make it colorful / grayscale).

Comment: der golem, the problem is, do I have to invalidate all then repaint? or is there any "better" way?

Comment: If you are using the canvas... that's the way. I'm just wondering why did you choose the **hard way**.